# Laravel count number out of database with relations

Tags: html, database, laravel, count

Got a few relations. A company hasMany workers, and a worker belongsTo a company.

Now I have a table with the company information and I want to have a column with a total amount of workers one company has.
Like this:
[image]

With the amount of workers in the 'medewerkers'(contributors/workers) table.

Now I've been trying some stuff and I can't figure it out.

**View:**

```
 @foreach($companies as $company)
 <tr>
     <td>{!! link_to_route('company.edit', $company->name, [$company->id] )!!}</td>
     <td>{{ $company->getTotalWorkers() }}</td>
     <td>{{ ' /' }}</td>
     <td>{{ $company->parent_id }}</td>
     <td>{{ ' /' }}</td>
     <td>{{ $company->active }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = Company::get();

    $getTotalWorkers = $this->company->getTotalWorkers();


    return view('company.index', ['companies' => $companies, 'getTotalWorkers' => $getTotalWorkers]);

}
```

**Model:**

```
class Company extends Eloquent{


    public function getTotalWorkers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User')->whereCompanyId($this->company_id)->count();

    }
```

This is what I have right one but will get a error any way:

> BadMethodCallException - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getTotalWorkers()

Any further information needed about my code can I post right away.

Comment: What does `$this->company` point to?

Comment: It is themeaning to have it count the amount of workers of only that company instead of counting ALL the workers from ALL the companies so I tried something out but it dosen't work obviously but I don't know what to do know to make it work, so it probably doesn't refer to anything which makes the problem

Answer (score 1):

If your `Company` model has an employees relation, then you could just count that:

```
class Company extends Eloquent {

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Employee');
    }

    public function numberOfEmployees()
    {
        return $this->employees()->count();
    }
}
```

In your controller, if you want a list of companies and the number of employees for each company, then you’re best off eager loading the employees relations and doing a count in your loop:

Controller action:

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = Company::with('employees')->get();

    return View::make('company.index', array('companies' => $companies));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($companies as $company)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{ $company->name }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $company->employees->count() }}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```